# oracle apex file upload

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to change the way APEX uploads files. I don't want files get into database tables as a BLOB. Instead, I want'em to get right to OS directory on the machine where apex is running. Is it possible? If so, what do I need to start with?

Answer (score 6):

The file browse item will always upload to a `BLOB` column. If not in a specified table, it'll go to `wwv_flow_files` (`apex_application_files`) which is the alternate option. That shouldn't be a dealbreaker though as you can easily clean up the table after you finish processing the `BLOB`.

- Determine the location where your files need to end up
- Make sure you have the necessary permissions! (read, write,...)
- Create a directory object in the database which refers to this
  location: [CREATE DIRECTORY statement documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5007.htm)
- Make sure you have the necessary grants on this object (read,
  write,...)
- Create a procedure that will write a `BLOB` to a file. An example of this
  technique is [here (dba-oracle.com)](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_writing_blob_clob_os_file.htm). In short, what that will do
  is:

  - open up a file on the filesystem (a directory is required, and a directory is referred to by the name of the directory object you
    created earlier!)

    ```
    -- define output directory
    l_output := utl_file.fopen('DIR_TEMP', 'filename','wb', 32760);
    ```

    In this example code, the created directory is the `DIR_TEMP` object
  - take the blob
  - read a piece of it
  - write that piece to the filesystem
  - repeat last 2 steps until the end of the blob has been reached (unless the `BLOB` is small enough to be written in 1 go)
  - set the file browse item to upload to `wwv_flow_files`
  - close the file (finish it)
- You could then alter that procedure to take a `BLOB` as in `IN`
  parameter.
- In apex, create an after-submit plsql process. You can call the
  file-writing procedure there, providing it with the stored blob.
- And clean up the upload table.

Example apex process:

```
DECLARE
   v_upl_blob BLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT blob_content 
     INTO v_upl_blob
     FROM wwv_flow_files
    WHERE name = :Px_FILE_BROWSE_ITEM;

   my_file_write_procedure(v_upl_blob);

   DELETE FROM wwv_flow_files
    WHERE name = :Px_FILE_BROWSE_ITEM;
END;
```

For even more documentation, there is of course always google, the oracle documentation on all objects used here, or even the oracle forums ([OTN apex forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=137) or [OTN PL/SQL forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=75) for example)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, tho I've already done it the way you described. The thing is I want to omit those steps (writing to BLOB column -> extracting to local directory). Seems it's not possible with APEX.

Comment: No, as far as i'm aware it is not. When a file has been uploaded to the server, you somehow need a handle to it, and a blob in a table is used for that. I can't think of a way where you skip all that. The files have to be uploaded to the server side. They have to be handled there.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare
  v_length number;
  v_id number;
begin
   select doc_size
   into v_length
   from   wwv_flow_files
   where  name = :P105_PIC;

if v_length > 20000 then
   delete from wwv_flow_files where name = :P105_PIC;
   commit;

    apex_error.add_error (
    p_message          => 'Cannot upload pictures bigger than 20kB!',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );

end if;
exception
 when others then
    apex_error.add_error (
    p_message          => 'Cannot upload pictures!',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
end;
```

Comment: This code does not do what the question asks about; your code is deleting a file.